# Webpack-dev-server plugin tap hooks

Tags: webpack, hook, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, tap

Under webpack-4's new plugin tap methods, is it possible to hook into a **webpack-dev-server** build, and obtain build error details?

I've tried both compiler's **invalid** and compilation's **failedModule**.

Compiler's **invalid** seems to work, but only after building twice and only returns a file path. Compilation's **failedModule** just never gets accessed due to running webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into [`done`](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#done) and then use the [`Stats`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/3b344f24741bf7e55277d7e62134ad4bb64ac945/lib/Stats.js#L73-L85) instance.

It has some useful helpers:

```
stats.hasErrors()
stats.hasWarnings()
```

The errors and warnings are read from the [`Compilation`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/3b344f24741bf7e55277d7e62134ad4bb64ac945/lib/Compilation.js#L2214-L2216) instance.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
Documentation says the done hook is a AsyncSeriesHook, which I translated as needing to be done.tapAsync, however build will never complete if done is set to tabAsync. So for the sakes of others out there, be-sure to set done to done.tap instead.